# Transpose a table with datetime records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to transpose a temp table (`Result` column is of `DATETIME` datatype) below to aggregate records based on `MeasureDSC` values (make two new columns: `First` and `Next`).

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (v14.0.17224.0) and Management Studio.

Current table:

```
+-----------+----------+------------------+------------------+---------+------------+
|    vID    |   fID    |      RESULT      |     Recorded     | LineNBR | MeasureDSC |
+-----------+----------+------------------+------------------+---------+------------+
| 292837518 | 75174227 | 2018-01-01 12:53 | 2018-01-01 9:48  |       1 | First      |
| 292837518 | 75174227 | 2018-01-01 12:54 | 2018-01-01 9:48  |       1 | Next       |
| 295376471 | 76107803 | 2018-01-01 22:51 | 2018-01-01 23:03 |       1 | First      |
| 295376471 | 76107803 | 2018-01-01 22:51 | 2018-01-01 23:03 |       1 | Next       |
| 301032810 | 78252847 | 2018-01-01 13:24 | 2018-01-01 13:45 |       1 | First      |
| 301032810 | 78252847 | NULL             | 2018-01-01 13:45 |       1 | Next       |
| 301867286 | 78566265 | 2018-01-01 14:40 | 2018-01-01 15:00 |       1 | First      |
| 301867286 | 78566265 | 2018-01-01 14:50 | 2018-01-01 15:00 |       1 | Next       |
| 302791918 | 78917501 | 2018-01-01 15:01 | 2018-01-01 7:30  |       1 | First      |
| 302791918 | 78917501 | 2018-01-01 15:05 | 2018-01-01 7:30  |       1 | Next       |
| 304444538 | 79538091 | 2018-01-01 8:00  | 2018-01-01 8:00  |       1 | First      |
| 304444538 | 79538091 | 2018-01-01 8:04  | 2018-01-01 8:00  |       1 | Next       |
| 304478684 | 79550758 | 2018-01-01 14:30 | 2018-01-01 17:44 |       1 | First      |
| 304478684 | 79550758 | 2018-01-01 15:30 | 2018-01-01 17:44 |       1 | Next       |
+-----------+----------+------------------+------------------+---------+------------+
```

The expecting output should be like this:

```
+-----------+----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|    vID    |   fID    |     Recorded     |      First       |       Next       |
+-----------+----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| 292837518 | 75174227 | 2018-01-01 9:48  | 2018-01-01 12:53 | 2018-01-01 12:54 |
| 295376471 | 76107803 | 2018-01-01 23:03 | 2018-01-01 22:51 | 2018-01-01 22:51 |
| 301032810 | 78252847 | 2018-01-01 13:45 | 2018-01-01 13:24 | NULL             |
| 301867286 | 78566265 | 2018-01-01 15:00 | 2018-01-01 14:40 | 2018-01-01 14:50 |
| 302791918 | 78917501 | 2018-01-01 7:30  | 2018-01-01 15:01 | 2018-01-01 15:05 |
| 304444538 | 79538091 | 2018-01-01 8:00  | 2018-01-01 8:00  | 2018-01-01 8:04  |
| 304478684 | 79550758 | 2018-01-01 17:44 | 2018-01-01 14:30 | 2018-01-01 15:30 |
+-----------+----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I was trying to use PIVOT function but getting an error message all the time: "Invalid column name 'RESULT'."

My code:

```
SELECT 
    vID, fID,
    RESULT,
    Recorded,
    [First] AS [First],
    [Next] AS [Next]
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         vID, fID, RESULT, Recorded, MeasureDSC
     FROM 
         #temp) x
PIVOT 
    (MAX(RESULT) FOR MeasureDSC IN ([First], [Next])) p
```

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: how format the table like text ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do aggregation instead :

```
SELECT vID, fID, Recorded,
       MAX(CASE WHEN MeasureDSC = 'First' THEN RESULT END) AS First,       
       MAX(CASE WHEN MeasureDSC = 'Next' THEN RESULT  END) AS Next
FROM #temp 
GROUP BY vID, fID, Recorded;
```

Comment: conditional aggregation doesn't work as it produces the same number of rows as original table with NULL values in new columns (First, Next). I need to get 7 records instead of 14

Comment: also I'm getting this error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: @Art. . . Make sure you didn't include `RESULT` column in `GROUP BY` & `SELECT` statement that is the only reason you get 14 rows instead of 7.

Comment: @Art. . . Yes wrong column defined in aggregated function `MAX()`. Check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use conditional aggregation:

```
select vID, fID, Recorded,
       max(case when MeasureDSC = 'First' then result end) as [First],
       max(case when MeasureDSC = 'Next' then result end) as [Next]
from #temp 
group by vID, fID, Recorded;
```

In your case, the results seem sequential, so it looks like this can be simplified to:

```
select vID, fID, Recorded,
       min(result) as [First],
       max(result) as [Next]
from #temp 
group by vID, fID, Recorded;
```

Comment: conditional aggregation doesn't work as it produces the same number of rows with NULL values in new columns (First, Next). I need to get 7 records instead of 14.

Comment: @Art . . . In that case, you shouldn't select `RESULT` separately in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
with PTemp as
(
    select vID, fID, Recorded, MeasureDSC, RESULT from #temp
)
select vID,fID,Recorded,[First],[Next] from PTemp PIVOT (max(RESULT) for MeasureDSC in ([First],[Next])) as PivotTable;
```